# dired-x: How to set "Kill buffer of ..., too?" to yes without confirmation?

Tags: emacs, dired

If you delete a file `foo` in `dired-x`, you get asked `Kill buffer of foo, too?`. How can I skip this question and always answer it with `yes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers are stale, Since 26.1 Emacs provide a option to skip confirmation

```
(setq dired-clean-confirm-killing-deleted-buffers nil)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can advise the `dired-delete-entry` function so that any file buffers are closed before the deletion:

```
(defadvice dired-delete-entry (before force-clean-up-buffers (file) activate)
  (kill-buffer (get-file-buffer file)))
```

The Elisp manual describes advising as "cleaner than redefining the whole function" and it is less likely to break if the definition of the function changes in the future.

Comment: I just realized that, unfortunately,  this is not behaving as expected . When I'm asked to kill the buffer, too, and I choose yes, I am still in the dired(-x) buffer showing me the remaining files. However, with your code, the following happens: When I delete a file (without being asked), it throws me in a different buffer instead of  just deleting the file without changing the buffer.

Answer (score 6):

Simply redefine dired-clean-up-after-deletion in dired-x.el.

```
;; redefine the definition in dired-x.el, so that we are not prompted
;; to remove buffers that were associated with deleted
;; files/directories

(eval-after-load  "dired-x" '(defun dired-clean-up-after-deletion (fn)
  "My. Clean up after a deleted file or directory FN.
Remove expanded subdir of deleted dir, if any."
  (save-excursion (and (cdr dired-subdir-alist)
                       (dired-goto-subdir fn)
                       (dired-kill-subdir)))

  ;; Offer to kill buffer of deleted file FN.
  (if dired-clean-up-buffers-too
      (progn
        (let ((buf (get-file-buffer fn)))
          (and buf
               (save-excursion ; you never know where kill-buffer leaves you
                 (kill-buffer buf))))
        (let ((buf-list (dired-buffers-for-dir (expand-file-name fn)))
              (buf nil))
          (and buf-list
               (while buf-list
                 (save-excursion (kill-buffer (car buf-list)))
                 (setq buf-list (cdr buf-list)))))))
  ;; Anything else?
  ))
```